# How do I record only a specific area of my desktop?

Tags: windows, video, video-editing

I have tried using Camstudio to record a specific area on my desktop. But every time I select a particular region it seems to offset it by a certain amount.

I have tried Jing-It, which mostly works fine but only allows a time limit of 5 minutes and only outputs swf format.

I have tried webineria and AViscreen and several others mentioned [here](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-screen-recording-softwares-for-creating-attractive-screencasts/). But none of them seem to do their job properly.

I was wondering if anyone has a used a free screen recording software which:

1. Outputs .avi videos
2. Allows the user to select what area of the desktop he/she wants to record.

Comment: Have you tried hypercam? Always worked for me

Comment: Looks good. Let me try that out.

Comment: I'm not sure how well the new version is... I still use Hypercam 2

Answer (score 0):

[Mirillis Action!](http://mirillis.com/en/products/action.html) allows you to record exactly the area of your screen that you want. It costs $30 for a personal licence, but there's a free trial available.

Comment: Where do I get it? What does it cost? What does it do differently? How do I use it? Please see: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers

Comment: http://mirillis.com/en/products/action.html Appears to be the link to what he's talking about.  I don't know if the original poster was looking for something commercial or free...